# (STM32L476RG) Flag setting (osThreadFlagsSet) crashes microcontroller when executed in an Interrupt (GPIO EXTI)

Tags: interrupt, stm32, interrupt-handling, rtos, cmsis

I am currently learning CMSIS-RTOS v2 and I have an issue that is bugging me and I can't find the answer I need.

I am using the STM32L476-Disco board and the joystick center button as an interrupt. I have a very simple Interrupt callback for my center joystick interrupt :

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){
    //osEventFlagsSet(evt_id,0x0001);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD5_GPIO_Port,LD5_Pin);
    osThreadFlagsSet(ThId_Led_Blink,0x0001);
}
```

When I call osThreadFlagsSet, the microcontroller freezes and nothing else happen. This is why I've put the HAL_GPIO_TogglePin : to see if the mcu was still responding or not.

I know that my interrupt resets correctly because when I only put my pin toggle, I can toggle the Led correctly.

ThId_Led_Blink is a ThreadId

```
osThreadId ThId_Led_Blink;
```

I've checked that the ID is set correctly in my debugger and it is (it's not null).

As you can see, I've tried with osEvenFlagsSet and I have the same result.

When I check the CMSIS_RTOS v2 documentation, it does specify that osThreadFlagsSet can be called from an ISR, but I am not sure if I need to do something else in that case for the Flags to be set correctly and resolve the issue when the ISR is hanging.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "The microcontroller freezes". With a debugger if you break you should be able to see exactly where in the code it is stuck. Or is the debug session crashing too ?

Comment: When I use my debugger, I can see it goes to osThreadFlagsSet, but after that the debugger freezes as well as the mcu. I need to restart my debugging session again to be able to use the mcu.

Comment: Are you sure the debugger freezes ? What debugger / IDE ?

Comment: I am using STM32CubeIde which is built on Eclipse and I am using GDB as my debugger with STLINK v2

Comment: It's strange that the debugger crashes. usually even if you get a hardfault, the debugger keeps running. Are you sure you are not in an infinite loop ? For example the default execption handler of STMicro HAl is an inifinite loop so you may have the idea that you are frozen (sorry you will find it obvious of you are experienced in debugging)

Comment: After poking around, I am just stuck in an infinite loop. However, I found the issue but cannot fix it.

For STM32 mcu, I need to set VIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_4) with FreeRTOS / CMSIS RTOS.

However, the function doesn't exist anywhere in the libraries created with my cubeIDE project and I cannot, for the life of me, find any info on that. Every website I find, and even the STM32 code and documentation refer to NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(), but I don't know where to get that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after frustrating hours of searching, I finally fixed my issue.

As described in this website : https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html, for STM32 microprocessor, you need to set the NVIC Group Priority to 4. If you look on freeRTOS, they are talking about putting this line in your code :

```
NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig( NVIC_PriorityGroup_4 );
```

However, the STM32 has it's own library for the NVIC and the correct function to set the priority group is :

```
HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(4);
```

Why go with the same name when you can change everything?

So make sure to call this function before your kernel initialization if you are using nested interrupts with FreeRTOS/CMSIS RTOS.

Also, make sure that your nested interrupt priority is in the range of configured interrupt priority for your FreeRTOS, otherwise, the osThreadFlagsSet function will fail automatically.